# Socket IO Client not emitting/receiving any events apart from connection and disconnect on Nginx Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io

First off, all of this is working locally.

I am using https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io to enable socket.io in my front-end of my react/redux app. However, I am unable to emit/receive any event in production.

The initial connection event is working fine and I see a 'Connected' in my server's log files.

I've enabled socket debugging and see the following message in the console on my browser => `socket.io-client:socket transport is open - connecting +0ms`

Locally all events are being fired fine but as soon as we move to production communication breaks down.

The only difference between the local site and production site is that you can access the app on /sub-dir/ where as local dev takes place on http://localhost:{PORT}/

I've been all over the web implementing potential fixes but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

My nginx has the following set up file:

```
    location /sub-dir/socket.io {
            # rewrite ^/sub-dir/socket.io(/.*)$ $1 break;
            # rewrite ^/sub-dir/socket.io(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3344;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /sub-dir/ {
            rewrite ^/sub-dir(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3344;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

app.js ( my front end entry-point )

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import routeDispatcher from './routeDispatcher.js';
import reducers from '../reducers';

import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import secrets from '../secrets.json';

const socket = io("https://hicarbyecar.com/admin-boards/", {path: '/admin-boards/socket.io', transport: 'websocket'});
const socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(
  socket,
  ['server/', 'HiBoards::', 'HiSocket::']
);

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('whaaat');
  socket.emit('Connected');
});

export default function createAppStore() {
  return createStore(
    reducers,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, routeDispatcher, socketIoMiddleware),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
    )
  );
}
```

Server.js

```
// setting up server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();            // initialising express() to app
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server, {path: '/admin-boards/'});  // io object with server as arg
var port = 3344;

var secrets = require('./secrets.json');

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('listening to ' + port + ' <<<');
});

var redis = require('redis').createClient;
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');

var pub = redis(secrets.redis.port, secrets.redis.host, { auth_pass: secrets.redis.pass });
var sub = redis(secrets.redis.port, secrets.redis.host, { auth_pass: secrets.redis.pass });

io.adapter(redisAdapter({ pubClient: pub, subClient: sub }));

// directing app to use files in __dirname
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../dist/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {});

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createPool(secrets.db);

// connection of client
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('Connected', function() {
        console.log("Connected Message Received");
        socket.emit('Welcome', { message: 'yo' });
  });
  socket.join('admin-room');
  var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['admin-room'].sockets;
  console.log(clients);
  console.log('connected');

  // client disconnected
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){ // reseving 'event' and doing function
        console.log('... user disconnected');
  });

});
```

Comment: If at all possible, you should probably try talking directly to the node.js server rather than going through Nginx.

Comment: @jcaron I'm not sure what this would look like?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?